# Laravel Eloquent WHERE not doing its job

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to remove an user using the following query:

```
User::whereNotNull('confirmation_code')->where(DB::raw("created_at < (NOW()-INTERVAL 2 DAY)"))->delete();
```

I also tried:

```
User::whereNotNull('confirmation_code')->where('created_at', '<', '(NOW()-INTERVAL 2 DAY)')->delete();
```

And other options as well. Is there anything to do with dates on Eloquent that doesn't allow this operation?

Comment: For future reference, you should use `->get()` to debug these kinds of things easier. If you're not getting results back, then you're not going to delete anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use date_sub when you want to manipulate dates. Like Jeroen Noten said, this would do the trick:

```
User::whereNotNull('confirmation_code')->where('created_at', '<', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)'))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `DATE_SUB` instead of `-`:

```
created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: For some reason, i had tried this before and it didn't work.. As Carlos answered, it has to be as DB::raw..